# Unable to bypass error code 4 when using HealthKit through the simulator

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, healthkit, error-code

I'm creating a new multiplatform app using the Xcode beta run on macOS Ventura beta. I want to use HealthKit to submit mindfulness minutes but I can't get it working. I created a new app with JUST this and I have the same issue so I came here hoping someone knows how to fix it.

The ContentView for the app is:

```
import SwiftUI
import HealthKit

struct ContentView: View {

// You need only a single HealthKit store per app. These are long-lived objects; you create the store once, and keep a reference for later use.
let myHealthStore = HKHealthStore()
let typestoRead = Set([HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: HKCategoryTypeIdentifier.mindfulSession)!])
let mindfulType = HKObjectType.categoryType(forIdentifier: .mindfulSession)

@State var message: String?

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
            Text("Health Data Available")
        } else {
            Text("Health Data NOT Available")
        }
        Button(action: {
            print("Setting 1 minute Mindfulness")
            let startTime = Date()
            let endTime = startTime.addingTimeInterval(2.0 * 60.0)
            print("From \(startTime) until \(endTime).")
            
            // Create a mindful session with the given start and end time
            let mindfullSample = HKCategorySample(type:mindfulType!, value: 0, start: startTime, end: endTime)

            // Save it to the health store
            myHealthStore.save(mindfullSample, withCompletion: { (success, error) -> Void in
                print("in completion")
                if error != nil {
                    print("error: \(error!)")
                    message = "Failure: \(error!)"
                    return
                }
                
                print("New data was saved in HealthKit: \(success)")
                message = "Success: \(success)"
            })
        }, label: {
            Text("Set 1 Minute Mindfulness")
        })
        .buttonStyle(.bordered)
        Divider()
        Text(message ?? "No Message.... yet")
    }
    .onAppear() {
        print("ContentView appears")
        myHealthStore.requestAuthorization(toShare: [], read: typestoRead) { (success, error) -> Void in
            if(success){
                // Read or write the HealthKit data
                print("success: \(success)")
            }
            else{
                // Authorization failure
                print("error: \(error!)")
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Additionally I went to Application, Target, Info, and pressed the plus sign to add the following PLIST values:

- Privacy - Health Records Usage Description
- Privacy - Health Update Usage Description
- Privacy - Health Share Usage Description

[image: The set PLIST values for Privacy - Health Share/Update/Records Usage Description]

I also went to Application > Target > Signing & Capabilities > and pressed the plus to add HealthKit and check off `Background Delivery`.

[image: Image of the HealthKit capabilities and what I checked off.]

This got me past the first error but now when I run it I either get an error code 1 or 4. One is understandable, when run on my iPad or Mac as apparently `Health data is unavailable on this device` but, when run on the iOS simulator I don't understand how to get past the error:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=4 "Missing application-identifier entitlement" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Missing application-identifier entitlement}
```

What am I missing? I looked online but most people with this error seem to be updating an app. This is a newly created app. Just in case I've uninstalled it and reinstalled it on the simulator, chose a different simulator, and created a new bare bones app. Any tips to access HealthKit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please confirm that there is a bundle id string listed in the entitlements plist for the `application-identifier` key? Error Code 4 is referring to that missing.

Comment: Sweet that worked. Didn't see it in the text auto-completion so didn't think it was available. For anyone coming across this I opened the entitlements file (file with yellow checkmark for the icon), manually added "application-identifier", switched the type to string, and entered my bundle identifier.